# How to use parameter passed from JSP to servlet and include it in find query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, jsp, mongodb-query

I have passed a parameter from a JSP to servlet. How do I include this in the find() query to search for that result in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have resolved all JSP/servlet stuff, take a look to [this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/) tutorial about Java Mongo Driver where you can find how to do that and other basics things.

Following this tutorial you can define filters in your query as follows:

```
package com.mongoclient.MongoHelloWorld;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;

import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;

public class MongoHelloWorldApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create Mongo connection to the DB
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost", 27017);

        // Select the DB
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("myDatabase");

        // Select the collection
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("myCollection");

        // Make the query
        Document myDoc = collection.find(eq("myField", "myValue")).first();

        // Print result
        System.out.println(myDoc.toJson());

     }
}
```

In the previous example I use **eq** for equality comparison but you have java class like **gt** or **lt** for inequality comparison, **and**, **or** and so on... You could check the doc for more examples.

Regards!

Comment: This helps. And how do I loop through my entire database if I wish to search for any field. This query works well with my first entry only and returns void obviosly if I search for other results.

Comment: First of all, you will loop over an entire collection, not the entire database. In case you want to iterate over differentes collections you should make separate queries. Then if you want to retrieve all matched documents simply remove the ".first()" part and assign the result to different variable. You can use iterators to loop inside the collection result.
Could you be more specific about " if I wish to search for any field"?
Are you thinking in somthing like OR conditions?

Comment: Here you have an example for iterates over simply find with no condition. 

`for (Document cur : collection.find()) {
    System.out.println(cur.toJson());
}`

Comment: Hello @ Emiliano Viotti I take input from a JSP page, get it in the servlet and use the variable to search in the mongodb collection to see if it is present.
So yes, I iterate over a collection.  Your previous example is well explained and works well if it is the first entry. But what if I want to search for a record that can exist in a collection of more than 10 entries? Like I said, I take a variable from a JSP and use it to search for records.
Thanks

Comment: And yes, once I get the result, I have to pass it again to the JSP page.

Comment: I have been able to get the results by referring to the code that you provided as an example. Thank you.
Could you help with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352116/passing-mongodb-block-from-a-servlet-to-a-jsp